# Large Inputbox text: how to show a list of more then 6 workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

SOLVED: *Problem was the maximum character limit of 255 characters of the inputbox.*

I use this VBA text to select one of the open workbooks (and copy that data to another one after). This list function does not work when there are more then 6 workbooks open. [It works fine as long as there are less then 7 workbooks open:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrHaz.png) Why?

```
For Each aWb In Application.Workbooks
    aCounter = aCounter + 1
    aListOfWbs = aListOfWbs & aCounter & " - " & aWb.Name & vbCrLf
    If aWb.Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then aSelect_default = aCounter
Next

aSelect_OG = Application.InputBox("Take data from workbook nr:" & _
            vbCrLf & _
            aListOfWbs & _
            vbCrLf, "2 tools, 1 record", 1) ', , "", Type:=2)
```

Comment: To me this works, even when more than 6 workbooks open. I have dimmed aWb as workbook, aCounter and aSelect_defoult as long and aListofWbs and aSelect_OG as string.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I just discovered it works on 18 workbooks max if they are named Book1 till Book18. After that I found the limitation here is the character limit that an inputbox is allowed to have (255, 254 shown).